# Is the zero set of a real polynomial union of smooth manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

> **Question:** If I have a non-zero polynomial $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ defined on
> $\mathbb R^n$, is it true that the zero set $$Z(P) = \{x \in \mathbb R^n:
> P(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 0\}$$ can be written as finite union of smooth
> submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$?

This is probably a very basic thing of real algebraic geometry, but I'm totally ignorant in the area. If the response is affirmative, can anyone provide a reference?

Comment: Note that e.g. for $x_1^2-x_2^3$, you need to split the one cuspy curve into three parts (one being a point)

Comment: This example is union of three manifolds, two open lines and one point.

Comment: The solution I was searching for is given by Tao here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262589/every-real-variety-contains-non-singular-points

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I originally thought the result was true just considering closed manifolds, but that is just false by your counter-example. But considering open manifolds as well, the result is true and that is enough for what I want. Thank you very much!